# printing validation message on the same screen without redirecting in PHP

Tags: php

Hi a newbie here and would appreciate much a little help. I have borrowed this from an online tutorial and trying to customize to my needs.

This works file but the output messages are print on another page/screen. Simply what I need id the validation messages are to be printed on the same page/screen without redirecting. I tried removing the `$location` from the function but doesn't seems to be helping me. How do I make all the validation messages appear in the `MSGPane`?

Thanks for the help.

Here goes the code;

```
<?php
$directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$uploadsDirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory_self . 'uploaded_files/';
$uploadForm = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'index.php';
$uploadSuccess = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$fieldname = 'file';
$errors = array(1 => 'php.ini max file size exceeded', 
                2 => 'html form max file size exceeded', 
                3 => 'file upload was only partial', 
                4 => 'no file was attached');

isset($_POST['submit'])
    or error('the upload form is neaded', $uploadForm);

($_FILES[$fieldname]['error'] == 0)
    or error($errors[$_FILES[$fieldname]['error']], $uploadForm);

@is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'])
    or error('not an HTTP upload', $uploadForm);

@getimagesize($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'])
    or error('only image uploads are allowed', $uploadForm);

$now = time();
while(file_exists($uploadFilename = $uploadsDirectory.$now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]['name']))
{
    $now++;
}

@move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], $uploadFilename)
    or error('receiving directory insuffiecient permission', $uploadForm);

header('Location: ' . $uploadSuccess);

}

function error($error, $location, $seconds = 5)
{
    header("Refresh: $seconds; URL=\"$location\"");

    echo "
    <div id='Upload'>\n\n
    <h1>Upload failure</h1><br>
    <p>An error has occured: 
    <span class='red'>. $error .</span><br>
    The upload form is reloading</p>
    </div>";
    exit;
}
$max_file_size = 3500000; // size in bytes
?>


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='MSGPane'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must remove this line `header("Refresh: $seconds; URL=\"$location\"");` from the function.
This line redirects the user to the location specifyed in **$location**.

EDIT: Also remove the line `exit;`.

Comment: I did that. But it just merely prevent you from being redirected to the original page you were. The message is not echoed/printed on the same screen.

Comment: Oh, yes sorry. I forgot something. Remove also the line `exit;`

Comment: it isnt an error. The message is printed on a different screen and got to hit browser back to return to original page.

Comment: Do you meand the succes message?