# Error function in PHP with file handling

Tags: php, error-handling

I've been working with a file upload script written in PHP.  But I can't find any documentation on the "or error()" function used.

Is this a php error function?  Or a function of the file handling library?  Trying to find documentation so I can make the necessary changes, and I am not coming up with anything in the PHP documentation.

Here is the relevant code segment:

```
 $errors = array(1 => 'php.ini max file size exceeded', 
                    2 => 'html form max file size exceeded', 
                    3 => 'file upload was only partial', 
                    4 => 'no file was attached');

($_FILES[$fieldname]['error'] == 0) or error($errors[$_FILES[$fieldname]['error']], $uploadForm);
    @is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'])
    or error('not an HTTP upload', $uploadForm);
```

Comment: there is no such thing as an `or` in PHP. it is represented with `||` while `&&` for `and`. i do believe those should be inside an if statement.

Comment: @hungrykoala [Yes there is.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) You can write it as `or`.

Comment: @ChrisBurton oh, my mistake then. but I still believe those should be inside an if statement. it doesn't make sense to write those lines like that.

Comment: @hungrykoala Logical operators are not explicitly for conditionals.

Comment: @ChrisBurton true but if left like that the first statement doesn't seem to do anything. unless you assign that into a variable. the second statement is plausible as it is used in as a function parameter though the error is suppressed.

Comment: This is where I'm confused as well.  I'm fairly competent with php, but the syntax here I'm not familiar with as I don't do much file handling.  Is there a better way to do this?  Or somewhere I can find documentation on the way this is written?

Comment: @Keith Are you using some kind of framework? Could be a helper.

Comment: @ChrisBurton Not particularly, just php 7 and the included modules.  The code is form processing, using the file handling (might be new to html 5?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`error` is not a function defined in PHP, it's some custom function.
If this is sample code, it's probably supposed to mean *"fill in your error handling logic here."*

---

```
foo() or bar();
```

This pattern is used as a replacement for `if (!foo()) bar();` here. `or` is the same as the `||` logical operator (except it has lower precedence, which we'll ignore here). It has the same characteristic as `||` in that it is *short-circuiting*: the right hand side will only be evaluated if the left hand side is *falsey*. So if `foo()` is "successful", `bar()` won't be executed. In concrete terms this means that `error()` is called if the left hand side expression "fails".

Using `or` instead of `if` is a stylistic choice; IMO it's a *bad* choice, and the fact that it produces questions like this is enough evidence for that.

Answer (score 0):

`error()` is not a native PHP function. It's probably just a custom function that adds nicer messages.

Here are the error codes that are elaborated in the $errors array:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: So, if I haven't defined this explicitly anywhere; then it just isn't doing anything? I had assumed it was a native function and never given it another thought.  The script didn't come with a library and I don't believe it is based on any includes either.

Comment: Hmm, I found some pages with that script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544357/php-array-to-trigger-error-message-on-file-upload for example. You should avoid copy-pasting code that you don't understand. If anything, use code examples from the (comments) on PHP.net's manual pages. The community is pretty active and upvotes usually point you to good code.